# Raspberry pi Zero ,Bluetooth Over ttyS0 or Serial0

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

In config I have used

> dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

I still want to use the bluetooth connection

How do I set bluetooth to use ttyS0 instead of ttyAMA0

A doc stated

> It is also necessary to edit /lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service and replace ttyAMA0 with ttyS0

But there is no such thing as ttyAMA0 in the hciuart.service

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly changed /boot/config.txt file and later rebooted your RPi, your Bluetooth should automatically be using ttyS0. You can check that by running

```
ls -l /dev
```

and looking for a line saying

```
serial1 -> ttyS0
```

If serial1 does not appear to be mapped to ttyS0, then I recommend checking if this line

```
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

is a right choice for your Raspberry Pi Zero. It has proved to work well for RPi 3&4, but you need to look it up if it is right also for the Zero.